# php multidimensional arrays read

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am trying to read some info from a multidimensional array and I have this:

```
        $data = array();
        $data2 = array();
        $data3 = array();


        $query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE tip_user='agent'");
        while($usr = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
                        $data[] = $usr;
        }

        $query2 = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE tip_user='tl'");
        while($tl = mysqli_fetch_array($query2))
            $data2[] = $tl;


        $data3[] = $data;
        array_push($data3, $data2);
        foreach ($data3 as $test) {
            ?????
         }
```

How can I access the `$data3` ? I was thinking about something like `$test[0]['field']` but it doesnt work. Help!

Thanks!

EDIT:

`$data3` looks like this:

```
Array(
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [0] => 39
                [id] => 39
                [1] => Ardeleanu
                [nume] => Ardeleanu
                [2] => Bogdan
                [prenume] => Bogdan
                [3] => admin
                [email] => admin
                [4] => 81dc9bdb52d04dc20036dbd8313ed055
                [pass] => 81dc9bdb52d04dc20036dbd8313ed055
            )
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [0] => 33
                [id] => 33
                [1] => Voinea
                [nume] => Voinea
                [2] => Ramona
                [prenume] => Ramona
                [3] => ramona.voinea
                [email] => ramona.voinea
                [4] => a384b6463fc216a5f8ecb6670f86456a
                [pass] => a384b6463fc216a5f8ecb6670f86456a
            )
      )
)
```

Comment: Why not to debug using `var_dump($test)` ?

Comment: How can we help you when we don't know how your data looks? data3 is probably multidimensional array and you're accessing it wrong.

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to programming and this platform. I've edited the post.

Comment: `WHERE tip_user IN ('agent', 'tl')` - gets you all data in one query.

Comment: This is just an example. I need to get data from different xls file so I cant apply your method deceze.

Answer (score 0):

Try $test[0][0]['field'].
The fields are a little deeper than you expected i guess.

Comment: I get "Illegal string offset 'field' "

Comment: yes that is an example: do you get anything with $data3[0][0]['email']?

Comment: I figured that out. I needed 2 foreach loops. Thanks!